# How to transpile dependencies with @vue/cli 4.3.1

Tags: webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, vue-cli, transpiler

I have an app that has to work in IE11

Some dependencies like *lodash* use fat arrows (=>) and i want to target them to transpile them in es5.

I consulted many other posts that address that problem but nothing seems to work in my case.
My chunk-vendors.js file constantly has the same number of fat arrows

Here are my settings so far

**babel.config.js**

```
process.env.VUE_CLI_BABEL_TRANSPILE_MODULES = true;
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
        '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
        {
        "useBuiltIns": "entry"
        }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    filenameHashing: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    productionSourceMap: false,
    transpileDependencies: ["lodash"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
...
},
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "ie 11"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  }
...
```

Comment: Try to install the the "[@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-arrow-functions)" and use it to transpile arrow function. Besides, by default babel-loader ignores all files inside node_modules. If you want to explicitly transpile a dependency with Babel, you can list it in the "[transpileDependencies](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#transpiledependencies)" option.

Comment: Thank you, this is new tome. As you can see in my vue.config.js file, i already use transpileDependencies to target lodash and it is precisely what i am trying to do.
However doesn't seem to do it's job and i can't figure why.

Comment: I have create a new Vue sample, it seems that after install babel or the [@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-arrow-functions), it could use the arrow function in the components without using the "transpileDependencies" option. You could have a try. If still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrançoisPothier I'm facing the exact same problem and was wondering if you managed to solve yours? If you have, would you be able and willing to help me out?

Comment: I am afraid it's an ongoing issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to either use below at the root of your code start or core-js and regenerator

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
```

You will also be using preset

```
babel-preset-env
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env

Comment: Thank you for your time, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.
I tried @babel/polyfill earlier and after i saw it was deprecated i gave it no more attention.
Also my app.js file is fine, it's about chunk-vendors.js, i cant seem to get the transpileDependencies option to work :\